# How to replace a entire string by searching sub-string?

Tags: notepad++

i have a paragraph in notepad ++ as below

```
abd sung aisdifj asdij_fn 
abd sung aisdifj asddjj_fn
abd sung aisdifj asdij_fn
abd sung aisdifj asdjj_fn
```

where ever the _fn is there the entire word should be replaced with abc.

The final result

```
abd sung aisdifj abc
abd sung aisdifj abc
abd sung aisdifj abc
abd sung aisdifj abc
```

Comment: Find what: [^ ]+_fn 
Replace with: abc

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\S+_fn\b`
- Replace with: `abc`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\S+         # 1 or more non space characters
_fn         # literally _fn
\b          # word boundary, to NOT match _fnxxx, remove it if not needed
```

**Result for given example:**

```
abd sung aisdifj abc
abd sung aisdifj abc
abd sung aisdifj abc
abd sung aisdifj abc
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]